# How to use PHP CS Fixer to make each method call on its own line in a chain of method calls?

Tags: php-cs-fixer

Code before processing:

```
$this->create()->content()
->asd($result)
    ->json($result);
```

Code after processing:

```
$this
    ->create()
    ->content()
    ->asd($result)
    ->json($result);
```

This option is also suitable, but the previous one is preferable:

```
$this->create()
    ->content()
    ->asd($result)
    ->json($result);
```